# how to use gettext in php?

Tags: php, gettext

I have a file `dk.po` and `dk.mo` in folder lang in my webdir.

How can I use this file? I have tried all, but I can not get it to work.

```
// Lang
putenv('LC_ALL=dk');
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'dk');

// Specify location of translation tables
bindtextdomain("dk", ROOT .'lang');

// Choose domain
textdomain("dk");
```

Comment: I'm wondering if it is necessary to called putenv('...') when setlocale is called before ?

Comment: @Leto as I understood, the putenv call is for Windows compatibility.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am working with this already:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ar_LY.utf8');
bindtextdomain("trans", $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/trans/locale');
textdomain("trans");
```

the language file path:

```
/var/www/trans/locale/ar_LY/LC_MESSAGES/trans.mo
```

and I think (not sure) that you have to use the same paths!

Answer (score 2):

this works for me
my file is named messages.mo

```
static function initialize_i18n() {
    $locale=App::$locale;        
    $locales_root = App::$root."locale";
    putenv('LANG='.$locale);
    putenv('LANGUAGE='.$locale);
    putenv('LC_ALL='.$locale);    
    putenv('LC_MESSAGES='.$locale); 
    setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale.".utf-8");   
    $domains = glob($locales_root.'/'.$locale.'/LC_MESSAGES/messages-*.mo');
    $current = basename($domains[0],'.mo');
    $timestamp = preg_replace('{messages-}i','',$current);
    bindtextdomain("messages",$locales_root);
    textdomain("messages");
}
```

Comment: hmmm, i not relly understand :/ i have file into this folder /var/www/domain.com/lang/dk/dk.mo 

can you make a sample out of this info?

Comment: im sorry for my variables .. substitute $locale with "lang/dk" and App::$root with "/var/www/domain.com/"

Answer (score -1):

I would seriously recommend using `Zend_Translate` for this as you can run into a lot of inconsistencies with `locales` on various types of systems.

Docs: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.translate.using.html

Comment: if i have a big project, can i out zend translate into this? or will it be hard?

Comment: Just grab the entire Zend library and include just the Zend Translate class and you should be good.

Comment: You will not need to use `gettext` php function, because Zend provides its own entire implementation of gettext. One thing though, your host *must* be using PHP5 or Zend won't work.